# Can the electric and magnetic field be considered as the medium of light?

Tags: electromagnetism

Ok, of course light doesn't need a medium. But is this really true?

Many waves like sound and water waves are just motions of a medium, so can light also be just the motion (excitation) of an electric and magnetic field?

Comment: This may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613722/129433

Comment: Look, in particular, at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/613724/74763) to the question that @Lambda linked. TLDR: It says that Michelson and Morley proved that the speed of light does not depend on the coordinate system in which it is measured and, that physicists therefore abandoned the idea of there being any medium. If you agree that the speed of light does not depend on the coordinate system, but you're still searching for a medium, then the word "medium" must mean something different for you than what it means for everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It depends on how you define medium. Light is an electromagnetic wave, and you are right in saying that light is the excitation of the electromagnetic fields. When people say "light doesn't need a medium", they mean that light doesn't need a *material* medium. This is something that truly baffled 19th century physicists, because they only had experience of water waves, sound waves, etc. which needs some bulk material to propagate.

Comment: If a field is not matter, what is it?....energy or....?

Comment: The current view of the physics is that you don't explain fields in terms of matter, but the other way round : you explain matter in terms of field. For example, what is an electron? Electron is an excitation of the electron field, just like photon is an excitation of the electromagnetic field.  These fields span all the space in the universe. They sometimes interact with each other (e.g. motion of electrons produces radiation, which is nothing but photons. ) This formalism is called as Quantum Field Theory.  What I have described here is quite hand-wavy, but it has a rigorous basis in QFT.

Answer (score -1):

At present  physics postulates that the underlying framework from which classical physical theories emerge is quantum mechanical, and described by the [standard model of particle physics](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) which has a number of elementary particles and three interactions between them.

So the classical electromagnetic waves  that are described by Maxwell equations emerge from a confluence of innumerable photons, elementary particles in the particle table of the standard model .

Photons carry the information of the electric and magnetic field they will build up, in their wavefunction which is a solution of a [quantized maxwell's equations.](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002/files/0604169.pdf)

So as far as the classical framework there is no medium. Considering the underlying quantum mechanical framework one may handwave that classical light rides on innumerable photons. [This link shows in quantum field theory](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) how the classical fields are built up from the quantum mechanical ones.

Comment: But is it true that a photon is not really a particle, it only behaves like this? If so, can a photon be just a motion of a field?

Comment: Going to the quantum field theory description of the photon,  the photon field on which the photon number operator acts, counts how many photons are there at (x,y,z,t), so it is a wave ( actually a wave packet)  on the photon field, but a quantized wave, photons are countable.  But the classical wave is another emergent level.

Comment: The pejorative statements used in the last referenced article were disappointing.